# <?php $x=11; if ($x++>11) { echo "$x"; } else { echo "not greater than $x"; } ?>

Tags: php

```
 <?php

 $x=11;
if ($x++>11)
{
    echo "$x";
}
else
{
    echo "not greater than $x";
}
?>
```

Output of this code is -
not greater than 12

I want to know why this happens.
Thanks!

Comment: Keyword: Postincrement

Comment: The question title should describe the problem in words, not just repeat the code.

Answer (score 1):

Due to [Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) and [Increment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php). The value is compared before it is incremented. Therefore, that condition is false. If you do `++$x` instead of `x$++`, then you will have a different result due to the pre and post increment. If you put brackets around `$x++` then it will be evaluated first and you will have it evaluated to true.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that there are two different incrementing operators. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php).

Basically:

- `$x++` uses `$x` as-is, then increments.
- `++$x` increments, then uses the variable.